# How to create self signed certificate with openssl 1.1.1

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, imap, x509certificate, postfix-mta

I used to use openssl 1.0.1f (Ubuntu 14.04) to create self signed certificate like below:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout postfix-domain.key -out postfix-domain.cert -outform PEM -keyform PEM -nodes -days 730
cat postfix-domain.cert postfix-domain.key > postfix-domain.pem
openssl gendh >> postfix-domain.pem
cp postfix-domain.pem /etc/ssl/certs/
```

But after upgrading to openssl 1.1.1 (Ubuntu 18.04), I always got error at `gendh` line

```
Invalid command 'gendh'; type "help" for a list.
```

What is the equivalent of `gendh` in openssl 1.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what generating DH parameters has to do with creating a self-signed certificate. You don't need to generate DH params to do that.

If you really do need to do it then you can achieve the same thing with `dhparam`, e.g.

```
openssl dhparam 2048 >dh.pem
```

Comment: The reason I used DH parameters was because of this error `postfix error: imapd-ssl: Unexpected SSL connection shutdown` (if not using DH parameters). Anyway, too many errors after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04. So for now I stay with 14.04. Perhaps for next time. Thank you anyway.